# How to check if string consists exclusively of ASCII characters in CMake?

Tags: string, cmake, character-encoding

We're using CMake to compile our software library. The problem is, that several new people were accepted to the team and they're using diacritics in their file/folder names.

Characters like `á,ř,š,ě,ž` are often incorrectly read by CMake Generators and subsequently the build fails with some obscure behavior (creating new folders with mangled names etc.).

---

#### My questions

1. Is there any way to modify the behavior of CMake to accept those characters? I'm especially interested in the value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`.
2. If the point 1 is not possible, is there any way to check the string to detect those non-ASCII characters and throw the error message subsequently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not that I'm aware of, and I could not find anything about it either.
2. Yes. It's not pretty, but the following example checks the input string for illegal characters and raises a build error if it finds one. In this simple example, it allows `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '\', '/', '-', '_', ':' and ' ' (space)`.

A step-by-step description of this particular solution might be:

- Set valid special characters (this should really be user-specified via a parameter)
- Get length of input and subtract 1 (zero-based index)
- iterate `[i..length-of-string - 1]` and get the corresponding character at that position from `_name`
- try matching the character to `A-Z` or `a-z`, if found, go to next character
- try matching the character to `0-9`, if found, go to next character
- try matching the character to any of the specified special characters, if found go to next character
- raise build error, since the current character is not a valid one

```
#
# validate_name(<name>)
#   Checks if the specified string consists of legal ASCII characters.
#   If an illegal character is found, then a build error is produced.
#   Legal characters are: A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and '\', '/', '-', '_', ':' and ' '.
#
#   _name:    The string to examine
#
#   Example: validate_name("C:\\foo\\bar")
#            validate_name("/home/user/code/project")
#
function(validate_name _name)
    # For simplicity, set all valid special characters here.
    set(valid_specials "\\\\/-_: ")
    string(LENGTH "${_name}" name_length)
    math(EXPR name_length "${name_length}-1")
    foreach(i RANGE 0 ${name_length})
        # Get next character.
        string(SUBSTRING "${_name}" ${i} 1 current_char)
        # Convert said character to lowercase. This way we don't have to consider
        # A-Z explicitly.
        string(TOLOWER ${current_char} current_char)
        # Is it A-Z or a-z?
        if (NOT (("${current_char}" STRLESS "a") OR ("${current_char}" STRGREATER "z")))
            # It's A-Z or a-z.
            continue()
        endif()
        # Is it a number?
        if (NOT (("${current_char}" STRLESS "0") OR ("${current_char}" STRGREATER "9")))
            # It's a number.
            continue()
        endif()
        # Is it a valid "special" character?
        string(FIND "${valid_specials}" "${current_char}" valid_special_found)
        if (valid_special_found GREATER -1)
            continue()
        endif()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "'${current_char}' is not a legal character in this context.")
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

If you want to keep the code size down, you can put all the allowed characters in a single string and use `string(FIND ...)`, much like what is being done with the special characters. Performance won't matter much anyway. I made it like this to make you aware of `STRLESS` etc.

Finally, in your case, you would call it with: `validate_name(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})`

Another possible solution is to simply use a regular expression:

```
set(NAME "home/user/path")
string(REGEX MATCH "[A-Za-z0-9 \\\\/:_-]*" MATCH "${NAME}")
if (NOT "${MATCH}" STREQUAL "${NAME}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Illegal character(s) found.")
endif()
```

This will produce a different string if any characters not defined by the rule is found. If the string is valid, then `MATCH == NAME`. Note that if the first character is illegal, `CMake` will throw its own error. I'm far from being a regex expert so I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

Anyway, I think this should get you started at least. Let me know if you need further clarification.